# embedded systems and formal methods

Tags: embedded, formal-methods

I'm working on a medical embedded systems project, similar to an infusion pump. We have a preliminary prototype, we are into second phase of the project. Here, we would like to do better by using formal methods. I have CS background, but don't have any experience in any of the formal tools or languages. I found some publications from UPenn and Arizona where they have used Uppaal, AADL etc. on an infusion pump prototype (http://www.fda.gov/medicaldevices/productsandmedicalprocedures/generalhospitaldevicesandsupplies/infusionpumps/ucm202511.htm). I want to ask the community on what are tools or languages (preferably open source) which could be used for the following purposes.

1) Currently, we have UI screens as state machines and there are lots of states. Are there formal tools to specify and embedded algorithms along with these screens? Can Z or TLA be used for this purpose?

2) Which tool(s) and languages should I use for describing software architecture and design? We don't have RTOS or complex hardware, it is just microcontrollers.

3) Tool to model and verify control algorithms and protocol state machines.

4) Tool to generate test cases from specifications.

Should I learn diverse languages or tools? Is there a minimal set of tools which would cover the above requirements?

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic here, unfortunately.